# Can "make" tell you the root cause(s) triggering build?

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make

Sometimes very small changes cause big rebuilds, but it's not always obvious why. **So, is it possible to get make to tell you what it believes changed and what it will trigger?**

Specifically, if possible, is there a way to do this without modifying the makefile itself?

Certainly `-n` will do a dry run and show all the commands it would run, but I'm looking for a list of dirty dependencies

Certainly `-d` will spit out a butt load of data somewhere in which the information I'm looking for is available, but I'm hoping for something that does not require more digging or scripting.

Comment: When configure the project, CMake just generates Makefile's. The build process is driven by `make` **only**, so you need to use make-related debugging. E.g, `make -d`.

Comment: I've found [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) very useful in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try specifying a [specific level of debugging output](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html) such as "basic"?

```
make --debug=b
```